# Creating a new tmux session from within a session

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, tmux

I am using a voice assistant on my RPi, but because of a certain tmux session I have, it won't work.

That is fine, because I came up with an idea to fix this.

Since my voice assistant is written in Python, I thought I could use the `os` module to do a `os.system('tmux kill-session -t Radio')`.

This works fine, but when I tried to create the session the session again, using `tmux new-session -d -s Radio 'python blah blah'`, it doesn't work, because I am trying to create a tmux session from within another.

Upon google, I found various suggestions, all of which didn't really fit my need (nor could be adapted).

What command could I execute from within Python from within a Tmux session, that could create a new tmux session, name it, and auto enter a command, but not be tied to the current session (Meaning I wouldn't have to attach to the voice assistant session to attach to the other one)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to unset the TMUX environment variable

```
# assuming this is the shell inside tmux
$ export TMUX=
# now you can run tmux inside tmux    
$ tmux
```

So the important line is `export TMUX=` prior to the inception of tmux.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but that didn't work. I use `os.system('export TMUX=')` but it doesn't create the new session at the end. Here is the relevant code http://pastebin.com/iAwAjEDQ

Comment: I can't help you out right now, I'll check back in a few days. But my first thought is there is probably a better way to approach your whole issue. Tmux inside Tmux feels very hackish.